# Can I invoke XMPPConnection.sendPacket from concurrent threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, xmpp, smack

**Motivation**

I want extra eyes to confirm that I am able to call this method *XMPPConnection.sendPacket( 
Packet )* concurrently. For my current code, I am invoking a List of Callables (max 3) in a serial fashion. Each Callable sends/receives XMPP packets on the one piece of XMPPConnection. I plan to parallelize these Callables by spinning off multiple threads & each Callable will invoke sendPacket on the shared XMPPConnection without synchronization.

**XMPPConnection**

```
class XMPPConnection
{
    private boolean connected = false;

    public boolean isConnected() 
    {
        return connected;
    }

    PacketWriter packetWriter;

    public void sendPacket( Packet packet ) 
    {
        if (!isConnected())
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not connected to server.");

        if (packet == null) 
            throw new NullPointerException("Packet is null.");

        packetWriter.sendPacket(packet);
    }
}
```

**PacketWriter**

```
class PacketWriter
{
    public void sendPacket(Packet packet) 
    {
        if (!done) {
            // Invoke interceptors for the new packet 
            // that is about to be sent. Interceptors
            // may modify the content of the packet.
            processInterceptors(packet);

            try {
                queue.put(packet);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            synchronized (queue) {
                queue.notifyAll();
            }

            // Process packet writer listeners. Note that we're 
            // using the sending thread so it's expected that 
            // listeners are fast.
            processListeners(packet);
    }

    protected PacketWriter( XMPPConnection connection ) 
    {
        this.queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Packet>(500, true);
        this.connection = connection;
        init();
    }
}
```

**What I conclude**

Since the PacketWriter is using a BlockingQueue, there is no problem with my intention to invoke sendPacket from multiple threads. Am I correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can send packets from different threads without any problems.

The Smack blocking queue is because what you can't do is let the different threads write the output stream at the same time. Smack takes the responsibility of synchronizing the output stream by writing it with a per packet granularity.

The pattern implemented by Smack is simply a typical producer/consumer concurrency pattern. You may have several producers (your threads) and only one consumer (the Smack's PacketWriter running in it's own thread).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough information here.

We don't know how the following are implemented:

- processInterceptors
- processListeners

Who reads / writes the 'done' variable?  If one thread sets it to true, then all the other threads will silently fail.

From a quick glance, this doesn't look thread safe, but there's no way to tell for sure from what you've posted.

Other issues:

- Why is PacketWriter a class member of XMPPConnectionwhen it's only used in one method?
- Why does PacketWriter have a XMPPConnection member var and not use it?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a BlockingQueue if you can restrict to Java 5+.

From the Java API docs, with a minor change to use ArrayBlockingQueue:

```
class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while(true) { queue.put(produce()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   Object produce() { ... }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     try {
       while(true) { consume(queue.take()); }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
   void consume(Object x) { ... }
 }

 class Setup {
   void main() {
     BlockingQueue q = new ArrayBlockingQueue();
     Producer p = new Producer(q);
     Consumer c1 = new Consumer(q);
     Consumer c2 = new Consumer(q);
     new Thread(p).start();
     new Thread(c1).start();
     new Thread(c2).start();
   }
 }
```

For your usage you'd have your real sender (holder of the actual connection) be the Consumer, and packet preparers/senders be the producers.

An interesting additional thought is that you could use a PriorityBlockingQueue to allow flash override XMPP packets that are sent before any other waiting packets.

Also, Glen's points on the design are good points. You might want to take a look at the Smack API (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) rather than creating your own.